# Issue To Select/Show DropDown Selected Value At Edit() In Asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

I Using Two Table User And Location In User Table I having LocationId And When I'm going to edit The User Form Then I need User With There Exact Location In Drop Down.but i didn't get that this is my code Of Controller:-

```
LogisticsEntities db = new LogisticsEntities();

RegisterModel Reg = new RegisterModel();

var tempUser = (from c in db.Users select new RegisterModel { _UserId = c.UserID, UserName = c.Name, Code = c.Code, Email = c.Email, Phone = c.Phone, JobRole = c.JobRole, StartDate = c.StartDate, EndDate = c.EndDate, LocationId = c.Location }).SingleOrDefault(x => x._UserId == id);

var varLocation = from Ls in db.Locations select Ls;

ViewData["LocationId"] = new SelectList(varLocation.ToList(), "LocationID", "Location1", "2");

if (tempUser != null)

return View(tempUser);

else

return View();
```

And In My View I Have code: -

```
@Html.DropDownList("LocationID", (SelectList)ViewData["LocationId"])
```

Thanx In Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `LocationID` as both first parameter of the dropdown and inside ViewData. In order to generate a dropdown you need 2 things: the first argument will be used to generate the name attribute of the dropdown and used to bind the value back and the second argument must represent a collection of SelectListItem that will be used to create the options of the dropdown. So try using a different key for the collection:

```
ViewData["locations"] = new SelectList(varLocation.ToList(), "LocationID", "Location1", "2");
```

and then:

```
@Html.DropDownList("LocationID", (SelectList)ViewData["locations"])
```

Comment: thank you for quick reply but i'm also try :
@Html.DropDownList("LocationID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["LocationId"]) but is also not working

Comment: i try  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LocationId, (SelectList)ViewData["Location"]) and it works Thank you Darin